# What is Plautus’s pun about frustum and frustrum?

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, spelling, plautus

The word *frustum* is often mispronounced as *frustrum.*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum#Notes) states that this mispronunciation goes back a long time and a pun about them is included in the [works of Plautus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plautus#Jokes_and_wordplay).

Can anyone direct me to this pun?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote a longer answer to this on the English language stack exchange, but in the migration process it got deleted. 
Shorter answer: the quote is **"ne sis frustra"** from Plautus's play [Miles Glorius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Gloriosus_(play)) and is a pun on **"ne si frusta"**. Wikipedia synopsis:

> [Pyrgopolynices] is ambushed by Periplectomenus, and his cook Cario.
>   The two men begin to beat him for trying to make advances on a married
>   woman. Pyrgopolynices begs them to stop; eventually giving the men a
>   hundred drachmae to halt their punches.

The more literal translation of ***ne si frustra*** is something like "don't fool yourself". Cario, demanding the money, [says](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/plautus-braggart_soldier/2011/pb_LCL163.301.xml) "otherwise you won't get away, don't fool yourself":

> aliter hinc non ibis, ne sis frustra.

***Ne sis frustra*** is [presumably](https://books.google.de/books?id=SFPUvjlSUIsC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=Plautus+frustum+frustrum&source=bl&ots=HNMxlq61or&sig=ACfU3U2gJUaNzn3e__-EeKTJilx6rdaGXg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimyb2d25PiAhUjsKQKHcctBrwQ6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=ne%20sis%20frustra&f=false) a pun on ***ne sis frusta*** -- that you not be cutlets -- alluding to the cook's knife and involuntary castration.

In another [English version](https://epdf.tips/queue/roman-laughter-the-comedy-of-plautus.html) the translators preserve the pun, having Cario say that the money is "to let you go without testifying" (testify-testicles ho ho).

Comment: Nice pun and great answer! Welcome to the Latin site. Don't hesitate to answer ans ask more!